# ImportError: Numpy openblaspy flavour needed error displayed even when i have scipy, numpy and scikit modules installed

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, pip

I am trying to run the following code:

```
# Gaussian Naive Bayes
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
# load the iris datasets
dataset = datasets.load_iris()
# fit a Naive Bayes model to the data
model = GaussianNB()
model.fit(dataset.data, dataset.target)
print(model)
# make predictions
expected = dataset.target
predicted = model.predict(dataset.data)
# summarize the fit of the model
print(metrics.classification_report(expected, predicted))
print(metrics.confusion_matrix(expected, predicted))
```

I have all the prerequisite modules installed like numpy, scipy, scikit-learn.

when i run the code the error displayed is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/sentiment-analysis/ldaex.py", line 4, in
   
    from sklearn import datasets
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn__init__.py", line 57, in 
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 9, in 
    from scipy import sparse
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy__init__.py", line 131, in 
    raise ImportError("numpy openblaspy flavour needed.")
   ImportError: numpy openblaspy flavour needed.

Can anyone let me know the problem in my modules???

Also when i try to run this following program, the same set of errors are displayed:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
categories = ['alt.atheism', 'soc.religion.christian','comp.graphics',    
         'sci.med']
twenty_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train',categories=categories,    
shuffle=True, random_state=42)
print twenty_train.target_names
```

Comment: Where did you get your scipy and numpy? Are their up to date? Have you tried installing them from official repos with pip?

Comment: try installing the Anaconda distribution of python

Comment: versions that i have are scipy - 0.15.1, scikit-learn 0.17.1, numpy 1.11.1
what is the link to official repos?